# How do I avoid a handler.postDelayed(Runnable run) from being called?

Tags: java, android-studio, asynchronous, bluetooth-lowenergy, postdelayed

I have this method to scan Bluetooth LE devices. The scanner runs asynchronously for 10s and then it is interrupted.

```
 public void startScanning() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
        }
    }, SCAN_PERIOD);
    btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
}
```

However, depending on a condition that is verified during the scan (for example, I find a device I was looking for, etc.), I call `btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback)`. So I don't want to call the stopScan after `SCAN_PERIOD` otherwise I'd call it twice. How do I avoid the second call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove call back:

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Comment: should I change my method as

`public Handler startScanning()  { ...
 ... 
 return handler;
}`  ?

Comment: @raff5184 no, just declare handler as Global variable and initialize it in the method. and before removing call backs just put a check if(handler!= null)

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable runnableRunner = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
    }
 }

public void startScanning() {
  final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
  handler.postDelayed(runnableRunner, SCAN_PERIOD);
  btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
}
```

Use [removeCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Object)) removes any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.

```
// cancel runnable whenever your condition is met.
handler.removeCallbacks(runnableRunner);
```

or use to remove all messages and callbacks

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another question on this problem.
I have a method `m()` in my "sequential" part of the code, not in the asynchronous one, that I need to call only if either the `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` is called, or after the `SCAN_PERIOD` has expired. How do I check these conditions and basically wait that one of the two happens? Do I need to put `m()` in a synchronous `run`?
(Now I also have the global `handler` that I can use)